# Powershell Remote Registry Access to Non-Domain Server

Tags: powershell, registry, remote-access

I have the following script which I use to collect the installed applications on various servers:

```
$results = @()
$list = Get-Content serverlist.txt
foreach ($computer in $list) {
  echo "Processing $($computer)"

  if (Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet ) {
    echo "Getting installed apps from $($computer) ..."
    $UninstallKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 
    echo "Opening remote registry ..."
    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computer) 
    echo "Getting registry keys ..."
    if ($reg) {
      $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 
      if ($regkey) {
        $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 
        echo "Building result object ..."
        foreach($key in $subkeys){
            $thisKey=$UninstallKey+"\\"+$key 
            $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computer
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"))
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))
            $results += $obj
        } 
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "$($computer) is DOWN!"
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computer
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value "Down"
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value "Down"
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value "Down"
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value "Down"
    $results += $obj
  }
}

$results | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation, Publisher | Export-Csv D:\Temp\InstalledApps.csv
```

This works fine on all of the domain member servers.  The issue comes when I try to get this to work on two non-domain Windows 2008R2 Standard servers.  One server works fine and the other server does not.  On the server that does not work, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "OpenSubKey" with "1" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed."
```

I cannot figure out why this would work for one server and not the other.  I am running the script from a non-elevated Powershell on a Windows 7 x64 machine.

UPDATE:

I used Process Monitor to track what the Remote Registry service was doing on both machines.  On the machine where things work OK, I see 4 reads of HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg and then it starts pulling the information I want from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.  On the machine where things are not working, Remote Registry does the same 4 reads of the winreg key but then it starts reading HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg\AllowedPaths and HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg\AllowedExactPaths.  I did some investigation and Remote Registry checks the permissions on the winreg key before proceeding.  I compared the good machine and bad machine and the registry keys and permissions are all exactly the same and are the default ones installed.

Comment: Is the querying account a local administrator on both servers?

Comment: Well, that's a good question.  I am running the script from a domain member Win 7 PC and I am logged in with my domain user account.  I have an administrator account on each non-domain machine with the same name and password as my domain account.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an actual cause or solution to this issue but I did find a workaround.  Adding the uninstall registry keys to the AllowedPaths entry allowed me to do what I want.  Not sure why one server requires this and the other doesn't but I can move ahead this way.